# Different keyboard layout on first login

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

When I first start my computer the default keyboard layout is set to en_GB instead of it_IT. When I then login the layout is correct and fixed, same as when I lock my computer, everything works fine.

Comment: The default keyboard it the first listed.

Comment: In my keyboard layout list there's only Itailan, no sign of English

Comment: Then how do you came to the conclusion the default keyboard is set to en_GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably chose en_GB when you installed the system. You can run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and select some other keyboard layout.